# Python flask with CORS, Chrome only HTTP POST results in OPTIONS request

Tags: python, flask, cors

I've built an API using python flask, with the CORS plugin. Cross origin requests are fine when using GET methods. In addition POST is fine with IE but not chrome, where I see a OPTIONS request and no subsequent POST. After reading lots about CORS and most of the documentation, I think my use of CORS should handle the OPTIONS request, but not luck.

My API code:

```
        from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify, request
        from flask.ext.cors import CORS, cross_origin #Used to get around the Cross domain request issue (e.g. when making a request to an entity of another origin (ip/domain + port))
        from DB import webAPIInterface
        import json

        DB = webAPIInterface()

        app = Flask(__name__)
        CORS(app)
        app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'



        @app.route('/api/v1.0/alarmArmedState', methods=['POST'])
        @cross_origin() # allow all origins all methods.
        def toggleAlarmArmedState():


            #DO stuff......
```

Note, I added the app.config['CORS_HEADERS'... and @cross_origin() later after lots of googling. Didn't seem to make much difference. I also tried different values here, including a content type of JSON (as that's what I use).

I also tried adding this:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-  Type,Authorization')
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
   return response
```

Please let me know your thoughts. Is there something obvious I'm missing to handle OPTIONS calls?

Comment: Can you post the response that you see for OPTIONS request?

Comment: Thanks for the response:  192.168.1.120 - - [14/Feb/2016 19:00:37] "OPTIONS /api/v1.0/alarmArmedState HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: I mean with the full response with headers etc. Can you create a gist and paste the link.